# Android recording application using audio record api

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am developing an Android application that records audio ..
Here is my MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

    public void start(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,RecordService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void stop(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,RecordService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }


}
```

and Service is

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class RecordService extends Service {
    AudioRecord ar;
    boolean isRecording = false;
    final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    int bufferSize;
    byte[] b;
    File f;
    OutputStream os;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        f = new File("ext_card/ex.pcm");
        startRecord();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopRecording();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startRecord(){
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        ar = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
        isRecording = true;
        b = new byte[bufferSize];
                try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while(isRecording){
                    ar.read(b, 0, bufferSize);
                    try {
                        os.write(b);
                        Log.i("File", "Writing file");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if(isRecording){
            ar.stop();
            ar.release();
        }
    }

}
```

But my problem is when click Start button(Start button calls `start(View v)`) Application gets stuck.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally my Self I found out the answer include saving file option in a different thread:

```
private void startRecord(){
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        ar = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
        isRecording = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        });
        t.start();


    }
```

Comment: But now the question is to possible to save file in some other format like mp3, wav or something else other than pcm

Comment: There is no way you could save the file in other format if you use AudioRecord class. This class records only RAW WAVE PCM. If you wish to use some compression codecs you shoud use MediaPlayer class for recording audio since it has some built in encoders like MP4A, AAC and others. Encoding to MP3 format could be done using 3rd party libs like lame or maybe ffdshow only. There will be no official support for MP3 encoding in android OS. Never. Only MP3 decoding supported.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the

```
f = new File("ext_card/ex.pcm");
```

actually could create the file? There is a proper way with

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to do it and this requires a permission in manifest to be set.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also if you wish a recording service working in seprarated from MainUI thread you could use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead.

Comment: you should first ask him a comment if he added the permission, if not add your answer

Comment: In android frame work sd card means it is parttion inside internal memory.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  will be path to that.If you want to access external_memory card which is a real memory card then you should do what I did

Comment: Actually Android Framework has ABSOLUTELY NO WAY TO WORK with card you had mentioned. It could only deal with SD card via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which requires a mentioned permission. External card just DOESN'T HAVE to be named "ext_card" since there is no standards and no framework for it. It relies to manufacturer only. So if manufacturer wish to name it like exter_sd, ext_sd, ex_card, extrnl_card etc it could do it and beleive me - they do whatever they want with it.